# PHP preg_replace() with exclusions

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace such string: `Karcher HDS-C 7/11, 9/15, 8/15-E` with `HDS-C 7/11, 9/15, 8/15-E`.

I use this pattern `/[^A-Z0-9\s\.\,\-\/\(\)]/` for `preg_replace`.
Instead of getting `HDS-C 7/11, 9/15, 8/15-E`, I'm getting `K HDS-C 7/11, 9/15, 8/15-E` with leading `K`.

So my rule: leave only words (1+ letters) in uppercase, 0-9, special chars; exclude words (2+ letters) that contain lowercase (first letter can be uppercase).

More examples (input => output):

`Karcher B 140 R Bp` => `B 140 R Bp`

`Yard-Man YM 84 M-W 31AY97KV643` => `YM 84 M-W 31AY97KV643`

How can I adjust my pattern to get it work?

I also need to filter 1+ leading words in lowercase (with possible first letter in uppercase).

For example:

`Karcher Karcher B 140 R Bp` => `B 140 R Bp`

`Karcher Karcher Karcher B 140 R Bp` => `B 140 R Bp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about targeting the words at the beginning, instead of trying to exclude everything else?

e.g.: `'/^(?:[A-Z][a-z-]+[A-Za-z-]* ?)+/'`

Comment: It didn't work for me. It doesn't work for 2 or more words in the beginning.

Comment: @Dreif I quickly edited it when I saw your update about the multiple words, try again now.

Comment: @Long Ears Still the same: "archer Karcher B 140 R Bp"

Comment: @Dreif did you copy it again or just use the same pattern? `echo preg_replace('/^(?:[A-Z][a-z-]+[A-Za-z-]* ?)+/', '', 'Karcher Karcher Karcher Yard-Man HDS-C 7/11, 9/15, 8/15-E');` gives me `HDS-C 7/11, 9/15, 8/15-E`

Comment: @Long Ears, You are right this line of code works, probably I messed up something in my code. Sorry. And I really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: @Long Ears, It doesn't work for "Portotacjnk karcher HDS-C 7/11, 9/15, 8/15-E". It returns "karcher HDS-C 7/11, 9/15, 8/15-E".

Comment: @Dreif '/^(?:[A-Z]?[a-z-]+[A-Za-z-]* ?)+/ should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to match everything after first whitespace ?

```
/.*? (.*)/
```

Comment: This works only if there is only one leading word in lowercase, but I need to filter 1+ leading words in lowercase.