# PHP preg_replace() Leave only words in uppercase

Tags: php, preg-replace, special-characters, uppercase, digit

How can I leave only words in uppercase, digits, special characters, or words where the first letter in uppercase, but it contains no more than 3 characters, with preg_replace.

For example:

**Portocjnk Karaer HDS-C 7/11, 9/15, 8/15-E** => ***HDS-C 7/11, 9/15, 8/15-E***

**Karcher Karcher B 140 R Bp** => ***B 140 R Bp***

**Karcher Karcher B 140 R Bsp Trr** => ***B 140 R Bsp Trr***

**Tatata Tatat Yard-Man YM 84 M-W 31AY97KV643** => ***YM 84 M-W 31AY97KV643***

**(Tatata) (Tatat) Yard-Man YM 84 M-W 31AY97KV643** => ***YM 84 M-W 31AY97KV643***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you tell that the 'B' in 'Karcher B' is part of the "must be kept" and not simply someone's initial?

Comment: If it is not followed by lowercase, I guess.

Comment: I think this is a complicated enough problem that you should parse it yourself rather than farming it out to the `preg_`* functions. If you do end up doing this, you want `preg_match_all`, not `preg_replace`. `preg_replace` takes a given regular expression and removes what's matched. You're starting out with what you want matched. Therefore you should use match rather than replace.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: What didn't work with yesterdays answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133133/php-preg-replace-with-exclusions/5133226#5133226

Comment: @mario, Yesterday we searched words in lowercase or with first letter in uppercase. But it's better to search uppercase. Or how can I improve yesterday answers to exclude such words like "(Tatat)", "Yard-Man", and even more I need to exclude Russian characters. So as I see it's better to search uppercase.

Comment: You could add `\(?` before and `)` in the character classes `[a-z..]` to have them included. And you could use `\p{Cyrillic}` to match russian letters. But true, a whitelist approach might be easier now. Add an example of the Russian strings.

Comment: @mario, `Cнегоуборочная машина "MTD" E740 F`, `Тратата (аэратор) бензиновый "Yard-Man" YM 3516 VO #40CM MTD`, `Cнегоуборочная машина MTD M 53`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('|\b([A-Z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z\-]*)\b|','',$text);
```

this one would work with most of your example

Answer (score 0):

This would be a simplistic whitelist approach. Instead of preg_replacing this will first extract the desired parts. And afterwards the $result array needs to be remerged.

```
preg_match_all('#\b[A-Z\d][A-Z\d/,-]*\b|\b(?<!-)[A-Z][a-z]{1,2}\b#', $str, $result);
$result = implode(" ", $result[0]);
```

You might need to add some more of the "special" characters in the second `[...]` character class.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world for some nice tools that might help in designing regular expression.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but it removes " from the string. `Tralala kulala "MTD" E740 F => MTD E740 F`, but it should be `Tralala kulala "MTD" E740 F => "MTD" E740 F`.